# upside down x_axis

Tags: core-plot, bar-chart

Am working with coreplot for creating bar-chart .Bar-chart is getting displayed but its upside down..X-axis starts at the top of the screen instead of being at the bottom of the screen..and even X-Axis isn't visible..It looks as if bars in the chart are hanging :(....How do I change its position and make it proper and even make x-Axis visible???

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self generateDataSamples];

    double xAxisStart = 0;
    double xAxisLength = 14;

    double yAxisStart = 0;
//  double yAxisLength = [[samples valueForKeyPath:@"@max.Y_VAL"] doubleValue];
    double yAxisLength = 190.0;


    CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];

    CPXYGraph *graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;


    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisStart)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength+1)];

    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(yAxisStart)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromDouble(yAxisLength+3)];

    CPBarPlot *plot = [[CPBarPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot.plotRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                 length:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength-5)];
    plot.barOffset = CPDecimalFromDouble(1.5);
    plot.dataSource = self;


    [graph addPlot:plot];
    [plot release];
    [graph release];
    [hostingView release];
}
```

Thank U

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to the plot area frame to make the axes visible:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 50.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0;
```

I'm not sure why the graph would appear upside down. Does the hosting view's superview have any transforms applied to it?

Comment: Hi ..problem is solved..actually I had created uiview above that I had created graph hosting view where graph was added..later everything was done in graph hosting view which gave me proper graph..  still in search of wat was the mistake with the previous code....

Comment: Now M getting similar problem with adding labels..M adding labels statically by passing array inside a loop and setting positions of x &y-axis..m passing color images array and label array..even here M getting upside down labels and color images..wat the problem might be...down is the code: